# Is it possible re-key OpenVPN on the fly

Tags: key-management, openvpn

Is it possible re-key OpenVPN on the fly with a new PSK without killing an restarting it with a new config?  it will be started with a PSK but i want to change it soon after start and periodically.

Comment: Seems unlikely.  If this is Linux the kernel will need to regenerate they keys and perform a new handshake.  During a normal rekey this is fine, but changing the config will require a restart of the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with a PSK. But what you ask for is something OpenVPN provides with it's TLS mode.  That will periodically negotiate new keys for you automatically.

If you do want the networking to be peer-to-peer, like in PSK mode, you can use configs similar to those in the loopback-server and loopback-client configs in the OpenVPN config files.

Something like this should work:

Peer 1;

```
remote peer.2.ip.address
local peer.1.ip.address
dev tun
verb 3
tls-server
dh dh2048.pem
ca ca.crt
key server.key
cert server.crt
tls-auth ta.key 0
```

Peer 2:

```
remote peer.1.ip.address
local peer.2.ip.address
dev tun
verb 3
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
ca ca.crt
key client.key
cert client.crt
tls-auth ta.key 1
```

You can use a tool like `easyrsa` to generate the ca and certificates.

Comment: at the time i believed that the PSK used by OpenVPN was random bits so i ass-u-me-d i could use a big hash of some data both ends share.  other than that my case has no means to share even the certs.  gonna have to spend more time thinking how to do this.  so this answer is useful ... just not for one situation i am working on.